# Inserting data from a form into SQLite3 database using PHP

Tags: php, database, pdo, sqlite

I am trying to create a registration from and then post the data into a SQlite databases file.

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="registerprocess_test.php" class="form-horizontal" id=
"register_form" method="post" name="register_form" role="form">
    <h2>Registration Form</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstname">First
        Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input autofocus="" class="form-control" id="firstname" name=
            "firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="lastname">Last
        Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input autofocus="" class="form-control" id="lastname" name=
            "lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="email">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username"
            placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for=
        "password">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
            placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="country">Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
                <option>
                    United Kingdom
                </option>
                <option>
                    United States
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input id="femaleRadio"
                    type="radio" value="Female">Female</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input id="maleRadio" name=
                    "gender" type="radio" value="Male">Male</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="checkbox"></div>
        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox">I accept <a href=
                    "#">Terms & Conditions</a></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type=
                "submit">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then my PHP looks like this:

```
 <?php
  try
{
//open the database
$db = new PDO('sqlite:users.db');


$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$country = $_POST["country"];


//Insert record  

$db->exec("INSERT INTO registered_users (firstname, lastname, username, password, gender, country) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password', '$gender', $country);");

//now output the data to a simple html table...
 print "<table border=1>";
 print "<tr><td>firstname</td><td>lastname</td><td>username</td><td>password</td><td>gender</td><td>country</td></tr>";
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM registered_users');
foreach($result as $row)
{
  print "<tr><td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['gender']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
}
print "</table>";

$db = NULL;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
print 'Exception : ' .$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I know I am **connecting** to the **database** as it **displays** the **current data** in the database in the table, upon **clicking submit**. However it does **not insert the data** from the registration form. Am I missing something important in my php code?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: DO I smell SQL injection too?

Comment: DO NOT use string manipulation on query strings! It is a huge security risk! Use prepared statements and query parameters instead.

Comment: @andrius, No I do not get an error.. 
Erwin Moller & Colonel Thirty Two, I am new to this so I do not know any different yet. I am just trying to get basic functionality working at present and will implement security at a later date

Comment: change the last part $country);" to '$country')");

Comment: you're not getting errors because you're probably not checking for them. As already stated by @MarkNg that variable `$country)` needs to be quoted, because it's more than likely a string.

Comment: your inputs are also broken up into seperate lines and that could have adverse effects.

Comment: Thank you. I changed $country) to '$country')"); as stated, but still no joy.

Comment: your code implies JS/bootstrap. Are you using that and Ajax by any chance and not showing us? Such as passing parameters in `data`? Like I said earlier, your inputs are broken up in seperate lines and that could cause you problems. Use error reporting, check for errors against your query and if using JS etc., check your console. There isn't much else I can say to help out here.

Comment: No i am not using Ajax. Thanks for all your help, I did some error checking, It was because I had another column within my table that I was not inserting into. So I deleted this column from the database and now it works fine. 

Thanks again

Comment: extra column in database will not stop your script from running either, its always a good practise during development to catch all error, use proper PDO and seriously, the password are in plain text...  ... ... ...

Comment: How do I capture errors using pdo?

Answer (score 0):

I did some error checking, It was because I had another column within my table that I was not inserting into. So I deleted this column from the database and now it works fine.